# Is it possible to generate a mock implementation based on static swagger service.json?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, doclet

I am generating the swagger *service.json* and other *resource.jsons* during the **maven build cycle** via the Carma **swagger-jaxrs-doclet**. Afterwards, I deploy the artifacts, together with swagger-ui on a webserver, and I can consult the generated documentation. This means that *I am not deploying a swagger bean* with my application!

Since swagger is mostly deployed along your API implementation, I was wondering which approach swagger-ui takes to make the docs executable. Does it redirect from the swagger-ui docs to the real implementation, or does it **create a mock-backend, based on the service.json**? I have read that it is possible to create a backend in node.js, based on the service.json, but I can't figure out how to do it in the web page. I even do not now **if it is possible** from within the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger-ui reads the swagger specifications you expose and exposes an html application that allows you to execute the API that is documented. It doesn't create a backend, it uses the swagger-js project to dynamically read the specification and execute the calls.

So for javascript based applications, you have swagger-js, but otherwise if you want to generate clients you can use swagger-codegen - https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen - which reads the specification files you have and allows you to perform various tasks like create clients, servers, static docs and so on.